# JAXB Reach Nested XmlElement Example

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations

*Here my XmlRoot class:*

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "IGE")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "IGEType", propOrder = { "altin" })
public class IGEType {


    @XmlElement(name = "ALTIN", required = true)
    protected List<ALTINType> altin;

    public List<ALTINType> getALTIN() {
        if (altin == null) {
            altin = new ArrayList<ALTINType>();
        }
        return this.altin;
    }
}
```

*Then successor(child) class of root :*

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ALTINType", propOrder = { "seanSytl" })
public class ALTINType {

    @XmlElement(name = "SEANSytl", required = true)
    protected SEANSytlType seanSytl;

}
```

*At last, successor class of successor of root :*

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "SEANSytlType", propOrder = { "birim", "oncekiKapanis", "enDusuk", "enYuksek", "kapanis", "agirlikliOrtalama", "islemHacmi", "islemMiktari", "bicim", "gram", "islemSayisi" })
public class SEANSytlType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String birim;
    @XmlElement(name = "onceki_kapanis", required = true)
    protected BigDecimal oncekiKapanis;
    @XmlElement(name = "en_dusuk", required = true)
    protected BigDecimal enDusuk;
    @XmlElement(name = "en_yuksek", required = true)
    protected BigDecimal enYuksek;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected BigDecimal kapanis;
    @XmlElement(name = "agirlikli_ortalama", required = true)
    protected BigDecimal agirlikliOrtalama;
    @XmlElement(name = "islem_hacmi", required = true)
    protected BigDecimal islemHacmi;
    @XmlElement(name = "islem_miktari", required = true)
    protected BigDecimal islemMiktari;
    @XmlElement(name = "BICIM", required = true)
    protected BigDecimal bicim;
    @XmlElement(name = "GRAM", required = true)
    protected BigDecimal gram;
    @XmlElement(name = "islem_sayisi")
    protected int islemSayisi;
}
```

*Myhandler class:*

```
@Override
    public void handleXMLtoIABData(RequestTcmbXMLData req) throws HmnServiceException {

        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(IGEType.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            File XMLfile = new File("C:\\Users\\U067944\\Desktop\\IAB_bülten.xml");
            IGEType igeRoot = (IGEType) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLfile);


            **List<SEANSytlType> listofAltinYtl = (List<SEANSytlType>) ((List<ALTINType>) igeRoot.getALTIN()).getSEANSytl();**


            for (SEANSytlType altinYtl : listofAltinYtl) {


            }

        } catch (JAXBException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

*In my handler class I try to reach last successor class (List SEANSytlType ), but it doesnt work.
I get this error :*

jvmId: [300], transactionId:[3005624292568000] .Root Cause: [java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.ykb.hmn.mdt.marketdata.xmlparser.iab.ALTINType]

*I also try this in handler but same:*

```
IGEType igeRoot = (IGEType) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLfile);

            String inputDate = igeRoot.getIGEBULTENGUNTR().getGun2();
             List<ALTINType> listAltinRoot = (List<ALTINType>) igeRoot.getALTIN();
             List<SEANSytlType> listofAltinYtl = (List<SEANSytlType>) listAltinRoot.get(0);
```

*Where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based your sample classes
     IGEType

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "IGE")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "IGE", propOrder = { "altin" })
public class IGEType {


    @XmlElement(name = "Altin", required = true)
    public List<ALTINType> altin;

    public List<ALTINType> getALTIN() {
        if (altin == null) {
            altin = new ArrayList<ALTINType>();
        }
        return this.altin;
    }
}
```

Then  ALTINType

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "altin", propOrder = { "seanSytl" })
public class ALTINType {

    @XmlElement(name = "SEANSytl", required = true)
    protected SEANSytlType seanSytl;

}
```

Then SEANSytlType

```
<!-- language: java -->      
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "SEANSytl", propOrder = { "birim"})
public class SEANSytlType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String birim;
}
```

Then sample class for test

```
 <!-- language: java --> 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(IGEType.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        File XMLfile = new File("sample1.xml");
        IGEType igeRoot = (IGEType) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLfile);

        List<ALTINType> listAltinRoot = igeRoot.getALTIN();

        // here you ll be have error ///
//            List<SEANSytlType> listofAltinYtl =  (List<SEANSytlType>)      listAltinRoot.get(0);
//
//            for (SEANSytlType altinYtl : listofAltinYtl) {
//              System.out.println(altinYtl.birim);
//            }

    } catch (JAXBException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So and and end sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IGE>
    <Altin>
        <SEANSytl>
            <birim>cccc</birim>
        </SEANSytl>
    </Altin>
    <Altin>
            <SEANSytl>
            <birim>dddd</birim>
        </SEANSytl>
    </Altin>

</IGE>
```

So basicly problem was that you have in root (IGE) childs list altin but in altin object thest is only 1 child object seansylt not at list like you have in altin so fix altin object add list there and take look at my example